# angularJS - Flask , $resource.save gives 405

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

My AngularJs resource  :

```
$scope.savePost = function(){
    var post = SavePost.save({

            title : $scope.title,
            content: $scope.content

        }, function(){
            console.log(post);

        })
}
```

And my flask api :

```
class SavePostView(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return {"args" : args}
```

Do I need to set up CORS ? I keep getting `405 , method not allowed error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind,

I did this while defining  my routes:

```
 api.add_resource(SavePostView, "/api/post/save", methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Works fine now.